# polymer core-header-panel scrollIntoView

Tags: polymer, core-elements

I thought I would get lucky and just do `window.scrollTo(0,500)` but that did not work because the core-header-panel is doing the scrolling for me.

Suppose you have two elements

```
 <core-header-panel>
  <core-animated-pages selected="{{s}}">
      <section><my-element select={{s}}></my-element></section>
      <section><my-element select={{s}}></my-element></section>
  </core-animated-pages>
 </core-header-panel>


</template>
```

I see the element I want to scroll to in the console but it does not scroll?

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="select">
 <template>
     ....
 </template>    
 <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
        select:0,
        selectChanged: function(){
            var x=this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#id")
            if (x){
                console.log(x)
                x.scrollIntoView()
            }
        }
    });
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

EDIT:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="select">
 <template>
     <core-animated-pages fit selected="{{select}}" id="core_page">
             ....
     </core-animated-pages>
 </template>    
 <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
        ready: function(){
            this.$.core_page.addEventListener("core-animated-pages-transition-end", function(e) {
                var x=this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#id")
                if (x){
                    console.log(x)
                    x.scrollIntoView()
                 }
             })
        }
    });
 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: `core-animated-pages` doesn't use scrolling. It uses css transforms to transition pages. Do you mean you want to scroll to a particular place inside a my-element, once it is selected?

Comment: yes, please :) that is correct, let say i click on a button in the first element and i want it to open the second page and scroll down to a place like you would do using a # in the url for example

Comment: PS then its the core-header-panel doing the scrolling right? I will change that in my question.

Comment: In my-element, implement `selectChanged` which calls `element.scrollIntoView()`. element would be a node in my-element's shadow dom to scroll to.

Comment: Aaaaa this does work :) setTimeout(function(){x.scrollIntoView()},1000) is there a better way than using setTimeout?

Comment: Can you listen for the `core-animated-pages-transition-end` that core-animated pages fires. Then do the scroll stuff once that happens?

Comment: Took me a while to realise only the parent of this element is doing a  animation. But on both cases the eventhandler was still too soon before it can scrollIntoView()?